# MS Visual Studio Community 2015 - how to source control an entire directory of projects

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I have a directory of solutions on my home development desktop where each solution resides in its own sub-directory, e.g.,:

- All-Soutions

  - Solution-A
  - Solution-B

I will be traveling a bit and would like to work on these solutions from a separate "traveling" laptop.

I have Git installed on my local machine and I have VS Community 2015 with the Git Extensions (3rd party) and the GitHub Extensions(3rd party) installed.  This same configuration will be installed on my 'traveling" laptop.

I have registered with GitHub.

I wish to use VS for as much of or all of this as possible.

All these solutions were developed on Xamarin and I have successfully "converted" them to compile and run using VS and a real Android device.

Simply stated, I want to get all of this under GitHub source/version control so all changes are stored and available/manageable from a single place, a GitHub remote repository, from both my home desktop and "traveling" laptop.

I have read many posts and watched several YouTube videos and this is not really covered in this context and environment, or clearly.

How do I do this in hopefully a simple cookbook form?

Regards,
Jim

Comment: Do you need to manage your repo from visual studio?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that, yes I wish to use VS for as much of or all of this as I can.  I edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Visual Studio plugin for Github can do that, but from git bash you can:

```
cd /All-Soutions/
git init
git add --all
```

Comment: OK, that's fine. then I can work from VS to do all the normal version controll stuff?

Comment: Actually does that git bash sequence create the remote repository on GitHub, a local repository on my desktop, or just setup git in each local directory?

Comment: it's only the local repo, it sets one repo for both projects together (not recommended though)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to do this from VS, but why not Windows Explorer and use [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/). This is what I have used svn/hg/git for years.

Comment: I already have that installed but updated it.  If I could impose, could you provide some comments on what I wish to do with an existing directory tree and getting it so it can be accessed/managed from other machines using GitHub/

Comment: This is a good guide [Getting Started](http://robertgreiner.com/2010/02/getting-started-with-git-and-tortoisegit-on-windows/). Basically, create a new folder in WinExplorer, when you right-click the folder you get an option "Git create repository here", this will create a new repository in github. Copy all your file/folders into new folder, right-click folder and "Git commit", this will send all your changes to github. From another machine, create new folder, right-click "Git clone", enter URL for your github, and will have all the files from the repository on another machine.